# actionscript 3 edit dynamic text in main fla from class file

Tags: actionscript-3

I am trying to code a card game, but I am stuck with a betting system...
Here is my script of .fla file:

```
set var pot:int = 0;
set var money:int = 100;
set var smoney:String = money + "$";

addChild(cash);
cash.text = String(smoney);
```

and here is the script of my class file:

```
package classes
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;

    public class Chip1 extends MovieClip
    {

        public static var pot:int;
        public static var money:int;
        public static var smoney;

        public function Chip1()
        {
            x = 8.35;
            y = 948.60;

            addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,chip1take);
            addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP,chip1bet);

        }
        function chip1take(event:MouseEvent):void
        {

            startDrag();
            scaleX = 1.1;
            scaleY = 1.1;
        }


        function chip1bet(event:MouseEvent):void
        {

            stopDrag();
            scaleX = 0.5;
            scaleY = 0.5;

            trace(dropTarget.name);

            if (dropTarget.name == "instance2")
            {
                pot +=  1;
                money -=  1;
                smoney = money + "$";

                addChild(cash);
                cash.text = String(smoney);

                removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,chip1take);
                removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP,chip1bet);

            }
            else
            {

                scaleX = 1;
                scaleY = 1;
                x = 8.35;
                y = 948.60;
            }



            trace(pot);
  }
 }
}
```

The problem is that I can't find a way to edit Dynamic Textfield "cash" from my class file, it just gives me an error 1120 because I haven't linked it to my .fla file.
So how can I do that?

I am new at as, still learning it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add these two lines to your imports:

```
import flash.display.DisplayObjectContainer;
import flash.text.TextField;
```

After that you'll be able to get the cash `TextField` in this way:

```
TextField(DisplayObjectContainer(stage.getChildAt(0)).getChildByName("cash")).text=String(smoney);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I've been stuck with this for days!

Comment: Sorry, forgot to do that :) Done now.